# Moving a spreadsheet tab in standalone Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a standalone Google Apps script that (among other things) moves a particular tab in a Sheets workbook to the leftmost position. When the script is bound to a spreadsheet, the following code works just fine:

```
      var tab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Current');
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(tab);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(1);
```

I can't figure out what I need to do to make it work in a standalone script. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Move A Sheet to position zero from Standalone Script

```
function moveSheetToZero(name="Current") {
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  const sh = dss.getSheetByName(name).activate();
  dss.moveActiveSheet(0);
}
```

Comment: Bueno! I was able to modify your suggested to code and add it to my existing function:

      const dss = SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook);
      const sh = dss.getSheetByName('Current').activate();
      dss.moveActiveSheet(0);

Answer (score 0):

You will need to 'open' the Spreadsheet in order to access it.

Although the Spreadsheet does not physically open, you will be able to modify it as normal using:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(...)
```

Or

```
SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(...)
```

You should however, avoid using the 'active' methods, instead, opt for `.getSheetByName()` and related methods found here:

[Spreadsheet Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

If you have further questions, please feel free to comment below!

Comment: Thanks, @NEWAZA. I'm a new to coding, so I'm still puzzling this out, but your advice to avoid "active" methods is a shove in the right direction.

Comment: Odd, I guess you can use `active` methods, just adds an extra step. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The code in my reply to Cooper's suggestion was mangled, so here it is again:

```
   const dss = SpreadsheetApp.open(workBook);
   const sh = dss.getSheetByName('Current').activate();
   dss.moveActiveSheet(0);
```

Works perfectly. Thanks for your help!